# Ruby cutting fields and saving

Tags: ruby, field, cut

I'm dealing with a file that has a bunch of entries like this

```
2012-07-15 10:16:27 C ?\path\to a filename\ called this file.doc
```

I want to take a line like this and cut the first 3 fields separated by spaces.
So...

```
var1 = 2012-07-15
var2 = 10:16:27
var3 = c
```

I've googled around and I just can not seem to find the right method to use. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you add the code you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby's [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) accepts a limit as its second parameter. This will do exactly what you're looking for:

```
irb(main):005:0> str = "2012-07-15 10:16:27 C ?\path\to a filename\ called this file.doc"
=> "2012-07-15 10:16:27 C ?path\to a filename called this file.doc"
irb(main):006:0> str.split " ", 4                                                        
=> ["2012-07-15", "10:16:27", "C", "?path\to a filename called this file.doc"]
```

You can use destructuring to assign these into local variables, if you want:

`one, two, three, rest = str.split " ", 4`

Answer (score 1):

The split method will do what you want:

```
string = '2012-07-15  10:16:27  C ?\path\to a filename\ called this file.doc'
date, time, drive =  string.split
```

Comment: wow... that was way easier than i was making it. Thanks so much

Comment: Not exactly, that splits too much, yielding: `["2012-07-15", "10:16:27", "C", "?\\path\\to", "a", "filename\\", "called", "this", "file.doc"]`.

Comment: Right. But only the first 3 elements are assigned to variables - the rest of it is ignored. I agree that jason's answer was better.